# Javascript - explode equivilent?

Tags: javascript, explode

So, I have a string with the delimiter | , one of the sections contains "123", is there a way to find this section and print the contents? 
something like PHP explode (but Javascript) and then a loop to find '123' maybe? :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Equivalent to Explode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514323/javascript-equivalent-to-explode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Equivalent to PHP Explode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514323/javascript-equivalent-to-php-explode)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
const string = "123|34|23|2342|234";
const arr = string.split('|');

for(let i in arr){
    if(arr[i] == 123) alert(arr[i]);
}
```

Or:

```
for(let i in arr){
    if(arr[i].indexOf('123') > -1) alert(arr[i]);
}
```

Or:

```
arr.forEach((el, i, arr) => if(arr[i].indexOf('123') > -1) alert(arr[i]) }
```

Or:

```
arr.forEach((el, i, arr) => if(el == '123') alert(arr[i]) }
```

Or:

```
const arr = "123|34|23|2342|234".split('|')

if(arr.some(el=>el == "123")) alert('123')
```

More information on [`string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) memeber functions.

Comment: How do I then locate the section with "123" and echo whatever else is in the section :o?

Comment: :) the section has more than just 123 in it though, so is there like a strstr() equivilient for Javascript?

Comment: Use the `match()` function; see my answer below.

Comment: @King review the documentation for the `JavaScript` string object and it's associated `methods` and `properties`...

Comment: `var string = "123 and stuf|34|23|2342|234", 
    arr = string.split('|'), 
    i; 
 
for(i in arr){ 
    if(arr[i].search(123) != -1) alert(arr[i]); 
} `

Answer (score 3):

You can use *`split()`* in JavaScript:

```
var txt = "123|1203|3123|1223|1523|1243|123",
    list = txt.split("|");

console.log(list);

for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    (list[i]==123) && (console.log("Found: "+i));  //This gets its place
}
```

**LIVE** DEMO: [***`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/LQRRB/`***](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/LQRRB/)

Answer (score 1):

`.split` is the equivalent of `explode`, whereas `.join` is the equivalent of `implode`.

```
var myString = 'red,green,blue'; 
var myArray = myString.split(','); //explode
var section = myArray[1];
var myString2 = myArray.join(';'); //implode
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var myString = "asd|3t6|2gj|123hhh", splitted = myString.split("|"), i;
for(i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++){ // You could use the 'in' operator, too 
    if(splitted[i].match("123")){
        // Do something
        alert(splitted[i]); // Alerts the entire contents between the original |'s 
        // In this case, it will alert "123hhh". 
    }
}
```