# Jquery - how to explode arrays value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to explode datas in array according to a charachter?

```
.each(myArr, function(key, value) { 

});
```

i take array like that

value is the values of array . Can explode value with "-" ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514323/javascript-equivalent-to-explode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514323/javascript-equivalent-to-explode)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var items = value.split('-');
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `split`

```
 var arr = str.split('-');
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you use [`value.split('-');`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this

```
function add_nik(id)
{
    $('#modal_form').modal('hide'); // show bootstrap modal
    var hasil=id.split(',');
    $('#nik').val(hasil[0]);
    $('#nama').val(hasil[1]);
}
```

in yout html code

```
<input type="text" name="nama" id="nama" >
<input type="text" name="nik" id="nik>
```