# JavaScript - how to separate string by commas (just like PHP explode function)

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing values which are separated by commas within the string I want to get each value just like I would with PHP explode, but I need to do it in JavaScript. Is there a way and how can be done?

Thanks

Leron

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Equivalent to Explode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514323/javascript-equivalent-to-explode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
"some,string,with,commas".split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mystring = "I like coffee, very much so, but I don't like...";
var exploded = mystring.split(",");
window.alert(exploded[1]);
```