# How to restrict user to only enter 12 hour time, with AM and PM

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is been available to allow user to only enter 12 hour time am/pm in a a field.

Extra: Any way i can validate 2 fields "from - to", for example: if user enter 1pm in the field from, the field call to will only allow from 1pm and forward.

Any help will be truly appertained. Thanks

Comment: one simple way : allow only numeric and then allow between 1 and 12 only

Comment: can you show the code that you're using to take input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need some code to parse the string and find problems. logic like this

- Does it contain a AM or PM (case insesensitive)
- Does it have a : and if it does then pull in the minutes, if not then asume it's only the hours.
- are there only numbers before the PM/AM? if not it's invalid.
- are any of the numbers greater than 12 or smaller than 1?

some usefull functions would probably be.

```
"string split".split(" "); // split into an array by spaces
```

[Javascript Equivalent to PHP Explode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514323/javascript-equivalent-to-php-explode)

```
"find the PM".indexOf('PM'); // return turns how many characters 
                             //away the PM is from the left.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

as well as slice()

```
 "slice after PM".slice(6); //this will slice from the beginning to the 6th character.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/g5CAY/1/)

[timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

i made it few months back this will help you.

```
$('#time2').attr('disabled', true);
$("#time").timepicker({
    timeOnly: true,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
}).change(function () {
    var val = this.value;
    if (val !== '') {
        var min = val.split(':');
        var min1 = min[1].split(' ');
        var minMin = parseInt(min1[0]);
        var minHour = ((min1[1] == 'am') ? parseInt(min[0]) : parseInt(min[0]) + 12);
        $('#time2').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hasDatepicker').timepicker({
            timeOnly: true,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
            hourMin: minHour,
        }).change(function () {
            var val_to = this.value;
            var min_to = val_to.split(':');
            var min1_to = min_to[1].split(' ');
            var minMin_to = parseInt(min1_to[0]);
            var minHour_to = ((min1_to[1] == 'am') ? parseInt(min_to[0]) : parseInt(min_to[0]) + 12);
            if(minHour_to == minHour && minMin_to <= minMin){
                this.value = val;
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#time2').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: how does that example answer the "12-hours-only AM/PM" question?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter i used timepicker plugin which does it for me.Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/g5CAY/1/).

Comment: sry, my bad - thought I saw 24 hours format on the demo page :)