# How to explode comma separated string to single index array using angular js or java script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a single string value like 15,16,17 and i want to convert it as ["15","16","17"]  using angular js 1.x or java script.Please help me

My Angular js code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

Array items
<code style="display: block; padding: 8px;">{{selected | json}}</code>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selected = [];
    $scope.selected = ["15","16","17"];
    $scope.existvalues=15,16,17;
    //$scope.selected=$scope.existvalues;
    /*Instead of above static code i want  assign a comma separated string  dynamic value like 
     this  $scope.existvalues=15,16,17;
     How i  convert and assign $scope.existvalues to $scope.selected array like ["15","16","17"] 
    */
     
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Equivalent to PHP Explode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514323/javascript-equivalent-to-php-explode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `split()` to convert a string to an array

```js
var str = "15,16,17"
var strArr = str.split(',');
console.log(strArr); // gives ["15","16","17"];
```

or to put it into terms as per your example

```
$scope.existvalues="15,16,17"; 
$scope.selected = $scope.existvalues.split(',');
console.log($scope.selected); // gives ["15","16","17"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method for strings, it will split the string based what you have asked it to split ("split by `,` here") and return the answer as an Array

```js
str =  "15,16,17"
strAsArray = str.split(",")
console.log(strAsArray)
```